# Parsing ftp url that username/password/path has special characters like @, /

Tags: parsing, url, ftp, special-characters

Generally, ftp url format is `ftp://user[:pass]@ip[:port]/path`

But now I got this string:

```
ftp://dude:1.1.1.1@1.1.1.1/@1.1.1.1/fml
```

It seems it's ambiguous because the parse result can be:

1. `password=1.1.1.1, path=@1.1.1.1/fml`
2. `password=1.1.1.1@1.1.1.1/, path=fml`

Should I have to just tell the client this is illegal, or is there any more friendly way to deal with it? Thanks..

Comment: You could always try encoding the `@` into `%40`, assuming your ftp client is URL-aware.

Comment: This works thank you. So I think I should tell the clients to follow the RFC document:)

Comment: I did not find any solution when both *login* and *password* contain the special character `@` :'(

Answer (score 5):

Special Characters in Usernames and Passwords

If your remote server requires authentication, you can include username and password in the input url string. Usernames and passwords should have the following special characters percent-encoded:

] [ ? / < ~ # ` ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | : " ; ' , > { space

Examples:

```
http://example.com/path/to/input.avi
https://example.com/path/to/input.mov
ftp://example.com/path/to/input.mp3
sftp://example.com/path/to/input.3gp
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/input.mpeg
s3://bucket-name/input.mpeg (shorthand for the full HTTP S3 url)
Examples (with username "user" and password "pass!word"):

http://user:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.avi
https://user:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mov
ftp://user:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mp3
sftp://user:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.3gp
ftp://user:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mp3
Some servers require the username include your domain name (username "user@example.com" and password "pass!word"):

http://user%40example.com:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.avi
https://user%40example.com:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mov
ftp://user%40example.com:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mp3
sftp://user%40example.com:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.3gp
ftp://user%40example.com:pass%21word@example.com/path/to/input.mp3
```